# How to use docker run with a Meteor image?

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell, docker, docker-compose

I have 2 containers mgmt-app who is a Meteor container and mgmt-mongo who is the MongoDB.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
7b65be4ac454        gitlab-lab:5005/dfc/mongo:latest          "/entrypoint.sh mongo"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    27017/tcp                mgmt-mongo
dff0b3c69c5f        gitlab-lab:5005/dfc/mgmt-docker-gui:lab   "/bin/sh -c 'sh $METE"   About an hour ago   Up 42 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp       mgmt-app
```

From my Docker host I want to run `docker run gitlab-lab:5005/dfc/mgmt-docker-gui:lab ls -al`

but I have this error:

```
=> Starting meteor app on port:80
/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
                        throw(ex);
                        ^
Error: MONGO_URL must be set in environment
```

So I tried:

```
docker run -e "MONGO_URL=mongodb://mgmt-mongo:27017/meteor" gitlab-lab:5005/dfc/mgmt-docker-gui:lab ls -al
```

and then the error was:

```
/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:313
                        throw(ex);
                        ^
MongoError: failed to connect to server [mgmt-mongo:27017] on first connect
```

I really don't understand because when I do a `docker-compose up -d` with this file:

```
mgmt-app:
    image: gitlab-lab:5005/dfc/mgmt-docker-gui:latest
    container_name: mgmt-app
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - $HOME/.docker:/root/.docker
      - /home/dockeradm/compose/area:/home/dockeradm/compose/area
    environment:
      - ROOT_URL=http://localhost:80
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mgmt-mongo:27017/meteor
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always

  mgmt-mongo:
    image: gitlab-lab:5005/dfc/mongo:latest
    container_name: mgmt-mongo
    volumes:
      - mgmt_mongo_data_config:/data/configdb
      - mgmt_mongo_data_db:/data/db
    restart: always
```

everything go well.

So my request is, how should I do my `docker run` to execute my command ? (the command is not a simple `ls -al` but it's ok for the demo)

Comment: Looks like a DNS resolution issue to me. Can you substitute the IP address for mgmt-mongo when setting the MONGO_URL parameter?

Comment: @RamanSailopal but why does it work with the `docker-compose`, in this one it's not the ip but the name ?

and the error is the same as with the name `failed to connect to server...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the containers separately with `docker run`, they are not linked on the same docker network so the mongo container is not accessible from the app container. To remedy this, you should use either:

1. [`--link`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/) to mark the app container as linked to the mongo container. This works, but is deprecated.
2. a [defined docker network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) for both containers to be linked by; this is more complex, but is the recommended architecture

By contrast, [docker-compose automatically adds both containers to the same docker network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), so they are immediately connectable without any extra configuration required:

> By default Compose sets up a single [network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.